# Animating horses and possibly other animals

Tags: animation, godot, blender

I'm adding centaurs to my game, good thing Blender has an add-on for animating animals, horrible that when exporting to GLTF these animations get distorted and ruined during the export process...

[Editor's note: this is the place where you show/describe the specific distortions you're seeing]

I tried this on multiple computers (also multiple blend files), and the issue persists, so it's either one of the many issues of the gltf format, an issue with the Blender add-on, or an issue with the animations/rigs.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I think this can be fixed in blender, and I doubt it is an export problem, it sounds more like a rigging problem. Are you sure you don't want to ask on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ (probably show the result you are getting)? - If it is the export... Godot got a new FBX importer in 4.3 dev 4 which avoids the GLTF conversion, so you could try exporting to FBX and importing with that. Finally, if you need a different tool for animation, you can try animating with cascadeur (it only supports FBX).